# only permit specific values in postgresql column

Tags: postgresql, constraints

What is the proper way to only permit specific values within a postgresql column?

Say I have a column named **colors**, varchar data type with a NOT NULL contstraint. I ONLY want to permit the value for a new row to be either White, Blue, or Black. Maybe they are products and we only make those specific colors.

Is the appropriate way to achieve this by using a `CHECK (color in("White", "Blue", "Black"))`

Is there any way to force the column to always be all upper or lowercase so that I can not worry about Blue vs blue?  Is the best way to deal with that via

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD CONSTRAINT CHECK (color = lower(color));
```

Is that the right way to ensure all new rows for the color entry are lowercase? Obviously i would need to update my check for the colors above to be "blue", etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD CONSTRAINT chk_only_white_blue_black
CHECK (color IN ('white', 'blue', 'black'));
```

That's all.
Single quotes, not double quotes.
No need to worry about upper case while only these three lower case words are allowed.

You might consider an [`enum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html) or a [foreign key](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) column pointing to a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

In case you have a known set of values (aka. enum), you should use an [enum type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html) instead, which not only enforces the values but also its case and has the benefit of consuming less storage on-disk and inside indexes, e.g.:

```sql
CREATE TYPE my_color AS ENUM ('White', 'Blue', 'Black');

CREATE TABLE my_table (
    ...
    color my_color,
    ...
);
```

For the check constraint version (in case you have an ever-expanding/dynamic set of values) you have already found the variant that should be best.